# PIP installed discord package can't be imported

Tags: python, pip, discord

So, I'm working on a project for a discord bot, however, it says
"Import "discord" could not be resolved" when I tried to import it. I have tried uninstall and reinstall it multiple times, I have same problem trying to import dotenv.

I am 100% sure that the package is installed.

Comment: Show logs. Are you using the correct python version?

Comment: Also, you can use virtual environments to avoid that kind of situations.

Comment: @drum Python 3.9.9

Comment: @DiegoRamirez But when I tried "(test) $ python -m pip install discord" it returned "Unexpected token $"

Comment: Maybe just running `python -m pip` on an activated virtualenv? Also, it would be great if you provide us the *entire error message* ;)

Comment: @DiegoRamirez Oh nevermind: At line:1 char:8
+ (test) $ python -m pip install discord
+        ~
Unexpected token '$' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

Comment: I agree with diego - a confusion that can happen is that on some systems it's "pip3" goes with "python3" and regular "pip" is pointing to the python 2.x install. To avoid that, do the install with the exact python binary you're using to run code, like "python3 -m pip install <packagename>" or "python -m pip install <packagename>".

Comment: @Dav_Did I was talking about the error with the imports (the main issue of your question). I don't know, 'Import "discord" could not be resolved' does not look familiar to me. The whole output would be fine.

Comment: I think the answer to this question depends a lot on the Python implementation (or also the interpreter) you are using. We need to know where did you execute your Python code that uses discord, and also if you have any kind of completion (fish, zsh, etc.).

Comment: @DiegoRamirez File "c:\Users\Dav_Did\hello\MBCbot\driver.py", line 3, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install discord.py`?

Comment: @FusionSid Requirements already satisfied.

Comment: Why don't you try `python3 [your file]`?